# Creating a for loop that adds / removes its conditions based on a variable inside

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

Context for this problem i am rendering a html table that is in short a price ladder. I only want to render 100 prices up and down from this centre price. So far i have achieved this but the ladder of prices does not change after running it the first time. Meaning that if the price went out the extremeties of the price ladder there would be nothing rendered.

Here is a quick diagram to explain what i am trying to achieve:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmTFq.png)

Here is my for loop declaration.

```
 for (var i = centrePrice + 100; i > centrePrice - 100; i -= consolidation) { rendering }
```

In short every time price moves up i want the for loop to account for this shifting everything rendered up by 1 and the same for a move down by 1 in price.

Here is an example of centreprice + 25

https://ibb.co/dkQvRJk

Comment: Maybe I'm stupid, but I definitely do not understand what you're trying to do here. Maybe a more complete example would help?

Comment: Welcome!
What is `consolidation`?
How does the (center) price move up or down?
Are the prices in an Array?  Are they set or do they get updated?

Comment: @iAmOren this is the consolidation function it is just there to batch prices into whole numbers as they are decimalised as they come into the script.  
   function consolidate(price) {
        return parseInt(price / consolidation) * consolidation
    }

Here is an example image of the ladder with centrePrice + 25 for some context:

https://ibb.co/dkQvRJk

The prices all build out from the centre price but do not adjust when the centre price changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something I coded:

```js
var prices=[];
for(var i=0;i<1000;i++) prices.push((Math.floor(9900*Math.random()+100)/100).toFixed(2));
prices.sort((a,b)=>+a-b);
var updown=4
var pIndex=2;

var msg="";
for(var i=pIndex+updown;i>=pIndex-updown;i--)
  msg+=(
    (i==pIndex?"*":" ")+
    (
      (i>0&&i<prices.length)
        ?(" ".repeat(6)+prices[i]).slice(-6)
        :"-".repeat(6)
    )+
  "\n");
console.log(msg);

pIndex=998;
var msg="";
for(var i=pIndex+updown;i>=pIndex-updown;i--)
  msg+=((i==pIndex?"*":" ")+((i>0&&i<prices.length)?(" ".repeat(6)+prices[i]).slice(-6):"-".repeat(6)))+"\n";
console.log(msg);

pIndex=500;
var msg="";
for(var i=pIndex+updown;i>=pIndex-updown;i--)
  msg+=((i==pIndex?"*":" ")+((i>0&&i<prices.length)?(" ".repeat(6)+prices[i]).slice(-6):"-".repeat(6)))+"\n";
console.log(msg);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Hope it helps somehow.

First couple of lines set prices array and gives random values - use your own values - however you get them.
updown=4 is for your 100 above and below.
pIndex is your centrePrice.
Then: msg is like your table row, and the for loop fills it:
looping i from higher to lower: pIndex+updown to pIndex-updown, one by one.
Using ternary condition: if true?then:else - first one to add an asterisk for center price.
second one to make sure index is within range of prices indexes:
If it is: show the price, if it isn't: show dashes.
string.repeat(6) repeats the string 6 times.
slice(-6) returns the last 6 characters (that's why I've padded with repeat because value can be shorter than 6 characters. - in td, use align=right).
\n adds a newline.
used that because console.log on stackoverflow snippet is limited.

The important parts are:

- the loop
- special treatment of center index (bold, color, asterisk, etc.)
- what to do when out of range (I assume not skipping - showing blank?)
- another test if above: td to the left, below: td to the right(?)

Comment: Thanks for this, could you explain a little whats going on? Cheers

Comment: Sure!
First couple of lines set prices array and gives random values - use your own values - however you get them.
updown=4 is for your 100 above and below.
pIndex is your centrePrice.
Then:
msg is like your table row,
and the for loop fills it:

Comment: looping i from higher to lower: pIndex+updown to pIndex-updown, one by one.
Using ternary condition: if true?then:else -
first one to add an asterisk for center price.
second one to make sure index is within range of prices indexes:

Comment: If it is: show the price, if it isn't: show dashes.
string.repeat(6) repeats the string 6 times.
slice(-6) returns the last 6 characters (that's why I've padded with repeat because value can be shorter than 6 characters. - in td, use align=right).

Comment: \n adds a newline.
used that because console.log on stackoverflow snippet is limited.

Comment: Added the "explanation" to the bottom of my answer (comments can become out of order...).

Comment: The important parts are the loop, higher/lower than center, center, out-of-range.
The repeat and slice and random and tofixed and sort are for demonstration to work, and probably not needed in table form.
Ternary conditions can be replaced with "standard" if(condition) do-if-true; else do-if-false.
ps. toFixed(d) converts a number to a string with d digits after the decimal - 0 would become "0.00", etc.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation i'll see if i can add some of my code into this and see what i come out with!

Comment: Great!
Let me know what happens!
Will you accept my answer?
And up-vote when you have 15+ reputation point?
Thanks!